# Android gmail doesn't appear in mail intent share list on nexus device(Tablet and phone)

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I' am facing the problem that "Android gmail doesn't appear in mail intent share list  on nexus device(Tablet and phone)".

```
      Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
      mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailTo);
      mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, buildSubject());
      mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, buildMessage());
      mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
      // mailIntent.setType("image/jpg");
      mailIntent.setType("plain/text");
      // mailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "send multiple datas"));
```

I tried  severals types ("image/jpg", "plain/text", "message/rfc822") but nothing

Can someone help me solving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using

```
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

This was just a bug in an old version of the gMail-app. The app wasn't registered to the intent's action and so it didn't appear in the suggested apps list.

By now this bug has been fixed and it works again.

Answer (score 1):

Try :  `Intent mailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mailIntent.setType("text/plain");` 
it should work.

Comment: Sorry. i tried already your proposal but you cannot send a multi data attachments